# VS Code. Выделение совпадающих фрагментов

Tags: text, visual-studio-code

Моя беда вот в чём, Visual Studio Code автоматически выделяет схожие фрагменты кода, очень удобно, не хотелось бы терять эту возможность.

Но если, например, обозначить переменную `K`, а другую - `K1`, то при наведении на `K`, Visual Studio Code выделяет все буквы `K` во всём коде, не самая удобная вещь.

Мой вопрос, можно ли как-то оставить включенной функцию нахождения подобных фрагментов кода, но сделать так, чтобы она работала только для полного совпадения слова?

Заранее спасибо.

[image: Пример выделения переменной]

Comment: Скопируйте техт кода и вставте здесь. Картинка не очень удобо.

Comment: @0xdb Так дело то не в коде, а в том, как VS Code его отображает, если я скопирую код, то вы не увидите тех выделений, о которых я спрашиваю. Но если вы настаиваете - то вот вам кусочек псевдо кода.

#include<iostream>
int main()
{
 int k, k1;
 k=5;
 k1=6;
 std::cout<<k+k1;
}

В этом примере при остановке курсора на k подсвечиваются все буквы k во всём коде, не очень-то и удобно, хочется, чтобы выделялась только заданная переменная k.

Comment: Извените,невнимательно прчитал вопрос.

Comment: Это реализовано по умолчанию. При выделении или двойном клике подсвечиваются совпадения текста, а при фокусе или одинарном клике подсвечивается, например, переменные. Во втором случае объявление переменной подсветится отдельным цветом, а вызовы отдельным.